# Body mouseleave triggered as mouse enters body

Tags: jquery, mouseleave, document-body

I want to trigger when a user is about to leave a page, using mouseleave - but if I wait for document ready before mouse enters the page,  the mouseleave is triggered o mouseentry! (Google Chrome) What have I done wrong please?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("body").bind("mouseleave",function(event) {

         $("#signup").width($(window).width());
         $("#signup").height($(window).height());
         $("#signup").css({'display':'block','position':'absolute','top':'0','left':'0','opacity':'0.6'});
        console.log('Window Width:'+$(window).width() +'Window Height:'+$(window).height());


    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
$(document).bind("mouseleave",function(event) {
     $("#signup").width($(window).width());
     $("#signup").height($(window).height());
     $("#signup").css({'display':'block','position':'absolute','top':'0','left':'0','opacity':'0.6'});
    console.log('Window Width:'+$(window).width() +'Window Height:'+$(window).height());
});
```

Comment: It's in a Wordpress plugin, so needs to be no conflict. Changing the $ s to jQuerys and it didn't trigger at all.

Comment: i forgot to change $("body") to $(document). Try with the changes

Comment: Interesting - it works in FF and IE latest versions bit not Chrome. Chrome fires as the mousenters the document area!

Comment: if you use body selector then it will trigger when you leave your content. So in case your content does not cover whole page then it will appear as you are entering your mouse but instead it will leave the body. So you should use document selector instead